# How to solve an error like "AssertionError: Data must have at least 5 non-missing values"?

Tags: python

I want to calculate ICC, so I tried to use a function "pg.intraclass_corr" like below.

```
import pingouin as pg

c_list = list(df.columns)
df_day = pd.read_excel(savefile)


for i in range(0, len(c_list)):
    res = f"{c_list[i]}: {pg.intraclass_corr(data=df_day,targets='dataSource',raters='Day',ratings=c_list[i],nan_policy='omit')}"
    print(res)
```

But it continuously gives me an error like "AssertionError: Data must have at least 5 non-missing values."
How can I fix it?

I've tried 'isna()' method and 'count()' method to figure out which columns of my data have fewer than five non-missing value, but it gives me nothing. So I think my data has enough amount of values.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, you need to include it properly formatted in your question

Comment: Can you please remove the image and replace it by your actual code in a code block. You can start/end a code block by placing three backtics (```)  on their own line.

Comment: @Only: I haven't seen your data of course (what's in df? what's in savefile? what's in 'dataSource'?), but when I got this error, it was because I misunderstood the meaning of 'targets': say you did measurements at n different settings, using k different methods, then 'targets' should look something like [1, 2, ..., n, 1, 2, ..., n], to indicate which rating belongs to which setting